# Network Boot Virtual Envirorment Instance

Tags: boot, virtual-machine, vmware, hyper-v, pxe

Is there a way I can boot a Hyper-V, VMware, or some sort of other virtual instance from another computer via something like PXE. I'd like to setup a diskless environment running Windows 8. Seeing as it should be diskless, I cant use any other software on the client machine. Is there any way I can accomplish this? I'd would like to install nothing but open source free software on the virtual instance so the clients can boot that OS and then run that software.

--EDIT--

Sorry...

I do not have a computers that are specifically designed to be diskless. I have computers that are supposed to run like a normal desktop/laptop setup. My goal is to PXE boot an operating system, not PXE boot an installation, PXE boot the entire OS. Is this possible with Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Diskless machines are supposed to be simple, for obvious reasons. Why do you need to boot a VM on a diskless pc? You can certainly boot via PXE a Linux machine, without the need of the Windows overhead. It would make your life much easier in this situation.

For instance, there is a Debian version that can be booted via PXE: it is FOSS, it is simple. You can find it [here](http://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst), with instructions and references to further instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, you should look into "openthinclient"

Comment: A bit more detail would improve this answer.